# Behavior of scanf when reading strings in C

Tags: c, string, scanf, buffer

I would like to know what does the compiler do with the whitespaces, newline character when using scanf("%s"). I know that scanf("%s") cannot read whitespaces and newline character.

For example if I enter

```
hi          question
```

or

```
hi

        question
```

scanf("%s") reads it without problems.

Below is the code that I am referring to

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    char str [2][50];
    scanf("%s", str[0]);
    scanf("%s", str[1]);
    printf("%s\n", str[0]);
    printf("%s\n", str[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**scanf documentation online:**

> Whitespace character: the function will read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters -- see isspace). A single whitespace in the format string validates any quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including none).

[source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

Comment: So in a way the values of str[1] is temporarily a whitespace character then it is changes when it reads a non whitespace?

Comment: So does this mean that scanf does not put the whitespace in the array?

Comment: @Janjan, correct. the white-spaces are never written to the array at all.

Comment: I have another question though. Is the behavior for gets() and fgets() similar with the only difference is that it reads spaces and tab characters and get written in the array. While all newline characters are ignored by gets() and fgets(), is that correct?

Comment: @Janjan: `gets` (which is no longer part of the standard library and should never be used under any circumstances) reads up to and *discards* the next newline.  `fgets` reads up to N characters or the next newline (whichever comes first).  If it reads the newline, it will be stored in the target buffer if there’s room.